# Spring Boot can't find LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer and OAuth2LoginConfigurer classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is the error I am getting when I try to debug the application or run it with coverage.

```
[2020.11.20 11:59:34] (Coverage): Error during class instrumentation: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Class not found
[2020.11.20 11:59:34] (Coverage): Error during class instrumentation: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2LoginConfigurer: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Class not found
```

I think that I might be missing a dependency but I have not been able to find a suitable one.
This is my **build.gradle** file.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '3.0'
}

group = 'com.tripsay'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.49"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```